# Use hobernate save data to MySQL get ultraedit

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I use hibernate to save data into MySQL, but I got ultraedit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYr2n.jpg)

My code is below:

```
@Test
public void testA(){

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setEmpName("邓海");
    emp.setWorkDate(new Date());

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.configure(); 
    SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(emp);
    ts.commit();
    session.close();
    sf.close();

}
```

And my .hbm.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.ypd.a.entity">
    <class name="Employee" table="t_employee">

        <id name="empId" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="empName" column="emp_name"></property>
    <property name="workDate" column="workDate"></property>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My hibernate.xml is :

```
hibernate-configuration >
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Edit**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKHxf.jpg)

If there is some settings I don't know? please show me the correct setting.

Comment: @224boy, How do you create the dababase?

Comment: @aircraft  I create it in navicate

Comment: @224boy, can you show me the charset ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your sessionFactory:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
```

You should appoint out the charset when you communication with the server.